# Dynamic Basic Auth Credentials in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I want to loop through different sets of credentials against a single request in the collection runner for Postman API Testing, but I'm not sure how best to dynamically set the credentials for each iteration?

Comment: You could add them to a JSON/CSV data file and then reference the keys/column headers in the Basic Auth using the `{{...}}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @DannyDainton I will try that